# curl SSL certification error

Tags: curl, meteor, ssl-certificate

I have been trying to install [meteor](https://www.meteor.com/install) on my macbook pro and have been facing problems with the certifications. I get the following error:

> curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in
>   certificate chain More details here:
>   https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>
> curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a
>   "bundle"  of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the
>   default  bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
>   using the --cacert option. If this HTTPS server uses a certificate
>   signed by a CA represented in  the bundle, the certificate
>   verification probably failed due to a  problem with the certificate
>   (it might be expired, or the name might  not match the domain name in
>   the URL). If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the
>   certificate, use  the -k (or --insecure) option.

After using `curl --insecure https://install.meteor.com | ssh`, I get the following error message:

> Downloading Meteor distribution
>
> curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer
>   certificate More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>
> curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a
>   "bundle"  of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the
>   default  bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
>   using the --cacert option. If this HTTPS server uses a certificate
>   signed by a CA represented in  the bundle, the certificate
>   verification probably failed due to a  problem with the certificate
>   (it might be expired, or the name might  not match the domain name in
>   the URL). If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the
>   certificate, use  the -k (or --insecure) option. Installation failed.

(Notice the installation failed message).

Please anyone help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance.
Edit:

After running `curl install.meteor.com | sh -x` like Fedor asked me to run I got the following message:

> - run_it
> - RELEASE=1.2.1
> - PREFIX=/usr/local
> - set -e
> - set -u
> - exec
>     ++ uname
> - UNAME=Darwin
> - '[' Darwin '>' MINGW -a Darwin '<' MINGX ']'
> - '[' Darwin '!=' Linux -a Darwin '!=' Darwin ']'
> - '[' Darwin = Darwin ']'
>     ++ uname -p
>     ++ sysctl -n hw.cpu64bit_capable
> - '[' i386 '!=' i386 -o 1 '!=' 1 ']'
> - grep BUNDLE_VERSION /usr/local/bin/meteor
> - PLATFORM=os.osx.x86_64
> - trap 'echo Installation failed.' EXIT
> - '[' -e /Users/usama/.meteor ']'
> - TARBALL_URL=https://d3sqy0vbqsdhku.cloudfront.net/packages-bootstrap/1.2.1/meteor-bootstrap-os.osx.x86_64.tar.gz
> - INSTALL_TMPDIR=/Users/usama/.meteor-install-tmp
> - rm -rf /Users/usama/.meteor-install-tmp
> - mkdir /Users/usama/.meteor-install-tmp
> - echo 'Downloading Meteor distribution' Downloading Meteor distribution
> - curl --progress-bar --fail https://d3sqy0vbqsdhku.cloudfront.net/packages-bootstrap/1.2.1/meteor-bootstrap-os.osx.x86_64.tar.gz
> - tar -xzf - -C /Users/usama/.meteor-install-tmp -o

Comment: please ask for more information if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled the OS and the error finished. I know this should not be the solution but this is what worked for me. I hope someone else posts a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer is: installation script that you download by itself calls curl to download tarball, and it does so without -k option:

```
$ curl -s https://install.meteor.com | grep curl
curl --progress-bar --fail "$TARBALL_URL" | tar -xzf - -C "$INSTALL_TMPDIR" -o
```

To press curl into it you can add --insecure to your curlrc:

```
$ echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc
```

Or just use http:

```
$ curl http://install.meteor.com
```

But i would strongly advise to look into problem itself - there might be someone MitM'ing you. Certificate of install.meteor.com seems fine to me.

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't understand terminal commands very much. After running the second command this is what Im getting:
_curl: (3) <url> malformed
tar: could not chdir to ' '_

Comment: I added the message in the question. please take a look after the "Edit:" part

Comment: Sorry, really can not see why curl considers provided url malformed. Does it start downloading if you run that curl manually? It should show progress bar if it was able to start http://pastebin.com/VYCE4QJ3

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I solve this issue.

1. Browse the install script in the web browser. (https://install.meteor.com/)
2. Save the script in your home as install_meteor.sh
3. In the Terminal, run `sh install_meteor.sh`

If you run like this, you will see that the error actually occurs in the installation script. What you have to do is to edit the script to make it ignore the certificate verification.

4. `vi install_meteor.sh` to edit the install script.
5. Look for the line `curl --progress-bar --fail "$TARBALL_URL" | tar -xzf - -C "$INSTALL_TMPDIR" -o`
6. Change this to `curl -k --progress-bar --fail "$TARBALL_URL" | tar -xzf - -C "$INSTALL_TMPDIR" -o`
7. Save it and run `sh install_meteor.sh` again.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when install on VMbox running Ubuntu 16 and routing through a VPN. After checking https://install.meteor.com in the browser the issue for me was that the CA was showing an expiration and also renewal date that had already passed.

The date of my VM machine was off by several days (*not sure how this happened*) and the time was being set automatically by my VPN which was located in a different county. Manually setting the date and time corrected the CA issue.

**Note:** In my case the date was off by 4 days, however, there is still a small window for this error to occur even if the time and date are set correctly — it just depends on when the CA expires and renews relative to your system date/time settings.  You can either try `curl` again in a day, or a quicker solution —  **set your date/time appropriately and try again.**